# Mock location Check failed with "Fake GPS Go"

Tags: android, locationmanager, android-fusedlocation

I am using the location service `(GoogleApiClient)` in my application and I have to check the received location is mock or not. I am using the `location.isFromMockProvider()` for checking, and it was working fine for higher version of devices with all fake gps applications.

Here I am adding the scenarios that will fail.

1. Take Samsung S7 (I got from S7) or any other high end device.
2. Install "Fake GPS Go" application and set a fake location
3. Check the received location `(location.isFromMockProvider() returns false)`

Thanks in advance.